# Class not found Error when running the application

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I'm working on an application with Laravel framework. When I tried loading the application(http://localhost/laravel/public/) from firefox browser, I get the below error:

**FatalErrorException in C:\wamp\www\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php line 150: Class 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider' not found**

I tried solving this by following few of the solutions mentioned below, but I couldn't get out.

1. I tried uninstalling the Composer and installing it with --dev-o and this didn't work for me.
2. I tried moving the folder Vendor out of my application(laravel) and then bringing it in by changing the composer.lock file. And this didn't work.
3. I tried renaming my namespace:
   C:\wamp\www\laravel>php artisan app:name laravel
   Even this gives me the same error: **[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider' not found**

My composer.json file components:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": { "php": ">=5.5.9", "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4", "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*", 
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0", "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["database"],
        "psr-4": {"App\\": "app/"}
    },
    "autoload-dev": {"classmap": ["tests/TestCase.php"]},
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": ["php artisan clear-compiled","php artisan optimize"],
        "pre-update-cmd": ["php artisan clear-compiled"],
        "post-update-cmd": ["php artisan optimize"],
        "post-root-package-install": ["php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"" ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": ["php artisan key:generate"]
    },
    "config": {"preferred-install": "dist"},
    "require": {"illuminate/html": "5.*","laravel/framework": "5.0.*"}
}
```

Your help will get me out of this limbo.

Comment: configuration: Laravel 5, PHP: 5.5.9

Comment: Can you post what you have in your `composer.json` file?

Comment: @James, should I change "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["database"],
        "psr-4": {"App\\": "app/"}
    }, to "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["database"],
        "psr-4": {"App\\": "laravel/"}
    },  ?

Comment: Try deleting this `"require": {"illuminate/html": "5.*","laravel/framework": "5.0.*"}` and putting `{"illuminate/html": "5.*"` up in the top require at the beginning. That is likely the source of your trouble - let me know how you get on.

Comment: @James, I've done as you had mentioned. I dont see a change in the behavior. Anything else from my code that can help you see through?

Comment: Did you add a package and then this happened after?

Comment: @James, I've been getting this error since, I updated my composer.json file. I've tried undoing it, but hasn't helped me. I looked at my files and think it might be due to namespace issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run

`composer install --no-dev --no-scripts`

and then

`composer install --no-dev -o`

Comment: I tried the two commands from CLI: For the first I got "Nothing to install or update Generating autoload files" message. For the second command, I got, "> php artisan clear-compiled

  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider' not found

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:"

Comment: Finally it had worked. Sorry for accepting the answer so late.

Comment: It doesn't Work for me!